# AJAX and Rails: two stacks or one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, eventmachine

Most of a web application is pretty standard CRUD. I need some data to be pushed to clients live as it's created. Is it worthwhile to run a separate, more lightweight stack (such as Sinatra or EventMachine) for the AJAX?

If I run one stack, I'll have Rails' overhead. This might require more Rails processes / servers, so how do I communicate between these without database queries? ZeroMQ? Finally, is Rails suited to handle hundreds of concurrent connections?

If I run two stacks, I'll need to duplicate authorization logic.

Which methods have been successful for you?

Comment: There are several questions in here. It might be worthwhile for you to articulate your concern. Are you having a problem scaling or is it something you expect to have a problem with? Obviously, some have scaled Rails apps but just like any other technology, you have to be clever to make things work just right.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3 you can pretty easily hook in Rack apps using the new routing syntax and inheriting your controllers from `ActionController::Metal` or just defining `self.call`.

Have a [read](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/222-rack-in-rails-3) (or watch) of Railscast #222 and check out [wycats' blog](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/12/20/generic-actions-in-rails-3/) (see below for example excerpts).

You're already aware of the additional cases you'll need to handle if you go down this track, so make sure it's necessary before getting stuck into it. It's usually cheaper to drop $ on servers than on programmers - hardware and bandwidth is pretty cheap.

I personally feel like this falls under 'premature optimization' unless you app is already running and choking up with too much traffic.

---

A few nice examples:

```
# config/routes.rb
# Hook in Sinatra
root :to => HomeApp
# Write your own barebones Rack compatible code
match "/processes" => ProcessesApp
# Even specify an inline proc
match "/heartbeat", :to => proc {|env| [200, {}, ["App is running"]] }

# /lib/home_app.rb
class HomeApp < Sinatra::Base  
  get "/" do  
    "Hello from Sinatra"  
  end  
end  

# lib/processes_app.rb
class ProcessesApp  
  def self.call(env)  
    [200, {}, [`ps -axcr -o "pid,pcpu, pmem, time, comm"`]]  
  end  
end
```